# How to plot a grouped bar plot from a list of pairs in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have this list of "coordinates":

```
   myList = [[0.7366771159874608, 0.6270718232044199], [0.7382352941176471, 0.6710182767624021], [0.7967479674796748, 0.656441717791411], [0.7296511627906976, 0.5727109515260324], [0.7992700729927007, 0.5833333333333334], [0.750788643533123, 0.5288888888888889], [0.851063829787234, 0.7423312883435583], [0.767515923566879, 0.5525114155251142]]
```

I want to create a grouped bar plot so that each of this pairs is close. The names of the column are just numbered from I to 8. I looked on the internet but it doesn't seem to me other people had this problem.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, y = zip(*mylist)
group_labels = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII']
plt.bar(x, y)

plt.title("Trial")
plt.show()
```

How should I change my dataset in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: Please don't name your list of coordinates "list". This term is a built-in type in Python - you will overwrite it in your code, rendering `list()` unusable. However, I do not understand your desired output. What is a stacked bar chart of x,y coordinates? What is stacked here in each group? Can you provide a sample output from the internet?

Comment: It is not stacked, but grouped, see this image: [link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_images/sphx_glr_barchart_001.png). The pairs of my list need to be grouped like in the image. Is it clearer now? (I also changed the name of the list, thanks!)

Comment: But this is directly from the [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html). What is the difficulty you ran into adapting this example to your needs?

Comment: I don't know what to put as an input, the examples online don't fit my case.

Comment: Why not? It seems you can simply substitute the variables: `x` is `men_means`, `y` is `women_means`, and `group_labels` is `labels`. Of course, you should rename your `x` - the sample code also uses a variable `x` for a different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from the docs.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ar = [[0.7366771159874608, 0.6270718232044199], 
      [0.7382352941176471, 0.6710182767624021], 
      [0.7967479674796748, 0.656441717791411], 
      [0.7296511627906976, 0.5727109515260324], 
      [0.7992700729927007, 0.5833333333333334], 
      [0.750788643533123, 0.5288888888888889], 
      [0.851063829787234, 0.7423312883435583], 
      [0.767515923566879, 0.5525114155251142]
     ]

xx, yy = zip(*ar)
group_labels = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII']
x = np.arange(len(group_labels))
width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, xx, width)
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, yy, width)
ax.set_xticklabels(group_labels)
ax
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you are trying to barplot more than one variables in the same barplot. The grouping that you are mentioning can be actually handled as plotting 2 different variables, man and woman.

Unfortunately, this is not natively implemented in matplotlib python, but you can use pandas to achieve the result you want. THe code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
myList = [[0.7366771159874608, 0.6270718232044199], [0.7382352941176471, 0.6710182767624021], [0.7967479674796748, 0.656441717791411], [0.7296511627906976, 0.5727109515260324], [0.7992700729927007, 0.5833333333333334], [0.750788643533123, 0.5288888888888889], [0.851063829787234, 0.7423312883435583], [0.767515923566879, 0.5525114155251142]]
x, y = zip(*myList)
group_labels = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[x, y], index=group_labels)
df.plot.bar()
```

Comment: If you want the matplotlib alternative then @venky__ posted a solution, however it will not work for more variables, in case for example you need 3 or 4, then a parametric function is needed